# ¿Por qué se convierte en un bucle infinito?

Tags: javascript, loops

```
let getRandomNumber = (min, max) => {
return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min) + min + 1);
};

let guestNumber = numMachine => {
let numPlayer;
do {
    numplayer = parseInt(prompt('Adivina el número'),10);
    if(numPlayer > numMachine){
        alert("Tú número es mayor que el de la máquina");
    } else if(numPlayer < numMachine){
        alert("Tú número es menor que el de la máquina");
    } else {
        alert("Adivinaste el número");
    }
}while(numplayer !== numMachine);
};
guestNumber(getRandomNumber(0,10));
```

Comment: Agrega tu función "getRandomNumber" :D

Comment: Puedes poner alguna imagen del resultado.

Comment: Muestra el mensaje como si hubiera acertado el número poniendo cualquier cosa y vuelve a preguntarte ... así hasta el infinito.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tienes un fallo al escribir `numPlayer` al cogerlo del `prompt`, te falta ponerlo en mayúsculas siendo `numPlayer` y no `numplayer` (nótese la P mayúscula). En la condición del while te pasa lo mismo.

El código corregido:

```
let getRandomNumber = (min, max) => {
return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min) + min + 1);
};

let guestNumber = numMachine => {
let numPlayer;
do {
    numPlayer = parseInt(prompt('Adivina el número'),10);
    if(numPlayer > numMachine){
        alert("Tú número es mayor que el de la máquina");
    } else if(numPlayer < numMachine){
        alert("Tú número es menor que el de la máquina");
    } else {
        alert("Adivinaste el número");
    }
}while(numPlayer !== numMachine);
};
guestNumber(getRandomNumber(0,10));
```

Comment: Jamas lo hubiera visto. Muchas gracias!